# switching over to awesome from openbox, can I still use my menu.xml

Tags: menu, openbox, awesome

I've been using openbox in LXDE for a couple of years now, and I have my menu.xml just the way I like it.  I see in awesome the default menu seems to be constructed in the rc.lua, but I also see that others have used different menus altogether (freedesktop menu for one).  Is there any way for me to use my menu.xml in awesome?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately not. , perhaps there's a openbox-menu to lua-script conversion script, but i have not seen one. i do encourage you to try creating one though. do one for me on the fly that lets me not have to re-do my pipemenu scripts.